# Cordova Build Failed: Error starting modern compiler

Tags: android, cordova, directory, sd-card

HI i am trying to generate cordova 3.5.1.jar .but getting the below error in my command prompt window.Can any one help to sp

> BUILD FAILED
>
> E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\too
> ls\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing
> this line:
> E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Error starting modern compiler
>
> Total time: 5 seconds

Comment: Your question title does not match your content.

Comment: Hi Raptor  thank you for quick response my question is i ma getting error starting modern compiler   while trying to generate cordova 3.5.1 jar

Comment: is it an expected result that the folder `too ls` have a space in between ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have messed up with your Java installation by accident.
If you want to troubleshoot Cordova build process you could run  command below:

`cd <path/to/project>
ant -v -f ./platforms/android/build.xml debug`

assuming that you are using `cordova` tool for the running build.